# How can i load 2 link in different tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

when click on the these links show first click in result 1 then click on second link show in result 2

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="result_1"></div>
<div id="result_2"></div>
```

Example (user click on link 1 then click on link 2) :

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="result_1" href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="result_2" href="link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="result_1">link1.hmtl</div>
<div id="result_2">link3.html</div>
```

then after click to other links remove the class and content

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="result_2" href="link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="result_1" href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="result_1">link4.hmtl</div>
<div id="result_2">link3.html</div>
```

i want do this with .load()
sorry for my bad English

Comment: How do you determine which div to use when you click a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstDiv = $("#result_1");
var secondDiv = $("#result_2");
$("a").toggle(function(){
     secondDiv.hide();
     secondDiv.load($(this).attr("href")).show();
   },function() {
     firstDiv.hide();
     secondDiv.load($(this).attr("href")).show();
  });
```

Comment: It's work but i want after second click remove content loaded in #result_1 and load clicked link

Comment: why do you need 2 divs then? how about on the second click you clear the content con the div and load the new one?

Comment: i have a compare list, i want compare 2 content beside them, and load just 2 content

Comment: i added one line " $("#result_1").hide();", that will hide the first content, when the second one is clicked, does that work for you? im no very clear about what you need

Comment: Thank you, but it's work once i want it countless, if click on link #1 load it in result1 if click on link #2 load it in result2 if click on link number #3 remove content in result1 and load link #3 and if click on link #4 remove content in result2 and load link #4 and ..., i have many link and cannot use if else :D

Comment: Thank you again, It's work but #result_1 and #result_2 is display:none and doesn't show anything